# Who is Tau'ma really?

Tags: comics, top-cow-universe, witchblade

Way back in issue #126 and #127 of Witchblade, a being named Tau'ma was manipulating Sara Pezzini (at that time, the bearer of the dark half of the Witchblade) into attacking Danielle Baptiste (at that time, bearer of the light half of the Witchblade).  Tau'ma has a confrontation with the Curator in issue #128, in which he mentions, "You think to again look on from a safe distance, moving your pawns and orchestrating events to your design," which is indicative that Tau'ma is aware of the Curator's manipulations.  Additionally, Tau'ma and the Curator call each other "brother."  Tau'ma disappears in issue #130, and hasn't been seen since.

In Artifacts #11, it is revealed that the 'big bad' of the Artifacts series, the Survivor,

> is actually the Curator, and has been manipulating Sara Pezzini and the other artifact bearers together in order to use their combined power to re-form the universe (to bring back his, which was destroyed).

In Artifacts #12, the Survivor

> enacts his plan, using the thirteen artifacts to destroy the universe.  Things go somewhat awry when he is killed by Jackie Estacado (the bearer of the Darkness) just before remaking the universe, leaving it up to Jackie and Sara to do it in Artifacts #13.

So who exactly is Tau'ma really, given that

> the Curator is from the previous iteration of the universe? Also, does he still exist post-remaking of the universe?

Comment: Spoilers tags/markup?